# How to calculate Volume between surface and a tangent plane

Tags: multivariable-calculus, volume, multiple-integral

I want to calculate the volume between  $c:\  4x^2+9y^2+z^2=36$ where $x>0,y>0,z>0$ and its tangent plane at the point $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$.

To find perpendicular vector $\vec{a}$ to the plane let $\vec{p}=4x_0^2+9y_0^2+z_0^2-36 \Rightarrow \vec{a}=\nabla\vec{p}=(8x_0,18y_0,2z_0)$ This means that the equation of the plane is:

$E:\   8x_0(x-x_0)+18y_0(y-y_0)+2z_0(z-z_0)=0$ and since $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ belong to $c$

$E:\   4x_0x+9y0y+z_0z=36$

What more do I need to calculate the requested volume? Can it be done somehow through the following integral?

$$\int^{z_0}_0\int^{y_0}_0\int^{x_0}_0 (4x^2+9y^2+z^2-36)\ \  dxdydz ?$$

Comment: What do you mean in this case "between"?  We're here in three dimensions, perhaps you're thinking of some projection of that ellipsoid onto some plane and then the volume of the body between that projection and the tangent plane...?

Comment: Basically it's the volume (in $x, y, z >0$ bounded by the tangent minus the the volume bounded by the ellipsoid.

Comment: @ArcticChar That sounds weird...what if the tangent plane is, say,  *not* perpendicular to one of the coordinate planes? What you describe could hardly be seen, in my opinion, as "volume between the tangent plane and the ellipsoind"...

Comment: Just take one less dimension, say $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ and $(x_0, y_0) = (1/\sqrt 2, 1/\sqrt 2)$. Then the tangent line to the circle is $x+y = \sqrt 2$ (which touches the circle from above) and the area (if I understand correctly) is that of the trianlge (with vertices $(0,0), (\sqrt 2, 0), (0,\sqrt 2)$ minus $\pi /4$ (which is the area of the circle in the first quadrant) @DonAntonio

Comment: Well, then it is the volume under the tangent plane and over a projection of the ellipsoid, minus the volume of that ellipsoide on that domain. Now it is clearer to me...

Comment: What does $ \displaystyle ~\int^{z_0}_0\int^{y_0}_0\int^{x_0}_0 (4x^2+9y^2+z^2-36)\ \  dx ~dy ~dz ~$ really mean? Have you understood the region?

Answer (score 1):

I will assume that $x_0,y_0,z_0>0$.

The region from the first octant bounded by $4x_0x+9y_0y+z_0z=36$ is$$\int_0^{\frac9{x_0}}\int_0^{\frac{36-4xx_0}{9y_0}}\int_0^{\frac{36-4x_0x-9y_0y}{z_0}}1\,\mathrm dz\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dx=\frac{216}{x_0y_0z_0}.$$On the other hand, the volume of the region of the first octant bounded by $4x^2+9y^2+z^2=36$ can be computed doing the substitution $X=2x$, $Y=3y$, and $Z=z$. It becomes $6$ times the volume of the region of the first octant which belongs to the sphere centered at $(0,0,0)$ with radius $6$; that is, it is equal to $1728\pi$. So, the volume that you are interested in is$$\frac{216}{x_0y_0z_0}-1728\pi.$$